# Search/Replace XML via Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, replace, find

I am looking for a way to have a powershell search through an XML doc searching for a specific ID that's within an "ID" tag, then locate the very next  tag and replace it's value with "true".  The IDs would be provided by the first column of a csv file.  Here is an example of the XML structure:

```
<primary>
<main>
<id>47</id>
<desc>foobar</desc>
<indicatorflag>false</indicatorflag>
</main>
</primary>
<primary>
<main>
<id>48</id>
<desc>foobar</desc>
<indicatorflag>false</indicatorflag>
</main>
</primary>
<primary>
<main>
<id>49</id>
<desc>foobar</desc>
<indicatorflag>false</indicatorflag>
</main>
</primary>
<primary>
<main>
<id>50</id>
<desc>foobar</desc>
<indicatorflag>false</indicatorflag>
</main>
</primary>
<primary>
<main>
<id>51</id>
<desc>foobar</desc>
<indicatorflag>false</indicatorflag>
</main>
</primary>
```

Now imagine the csv file has, in column 1:

```
47
49
```

I would like only those indicator flag tags to be updated to true.
Any help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: Just for clarity: when I said "the very next tag" I mean the very next <indicatorflag> tag.  I've attempted a regex find and replace, but it selects the last <indicatorflag> tag in the entire doc rather than the one within the same <primary> tag as the located ID

Comment: Your XML is invalid because it is missing a root element. Also, the csv with the id's to look for looks like a simple text file where each id is on a new line. Is that the actual format of the file?

Comment: yes it is in that format, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: **Don't use regex replace on xml**. PowerShell is very able to handle (valid) XML.

As commented, the XMLyou show is invalid as it is missing a root element.
After fixing the XML by encompassing it all inside a `<root>...</root>` element, you can read this in like this:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\input.xml' -Raw
```

Next, read the file to get the id's to update. If this file is like you show us, a text file where each id is on its own new line, use this:

```
$ids = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\ids.txt'
```

If however, this file **IS** a CSV file, something like

```
"ID","Something"
"47","Whatever"
"49","Anything"
```

then read the ids as array from it using:

```
$ids = (Import-Csv -Path  'D:\Test\ids.csv').ID
```

You can now loop over the id's and change the value of the belonging `<indicatorflag>` tag:

```
foreach ($id in $ids) {
    ($xml.root.primary.main | Where-Object {$_.id -eq $id}).indicatorflag = 'true'
}

# save the updated XML
$xml.Save('D:\Test\output.xml')
```

Comment: Thank you SO much!  This all makes sense.  I'll give it a try right now

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following XPath expression to find the `<indicatorflag>` node that's a sibling following the `<id>49</id>` node:

```xml
//id[. = 49]/following-sibling::indicatorflag
```

Generalize and use either `Select-Xml` or the `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode()` method to obtain the nodes:

```bsh
$xml = [xml]@'
<root>
<primary>
<main>
<id>48</id>
<desc>foobar</desc>
<indicatorflag>false</indicatorflag>
</main>
</primary>
<primary>
<main>
<id>49</id>
<desc>foobar</desc>
<indicatorflag>false</indicatorflag>
</main>
</primary>
</root>
'@

foreach($ID in 48,49){
  $ifNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//id[. = $ID]/following-sibling::indicatorflag")
  if($ifNode){
    $ifNode.InnerText = "false"
  }
}

$xml.Save("C:\path\to\output.xml")
```